# SlidingDrawer handle not visible

Tags: android, android-layout, slidingdrawer

I don't understand why in such layout black box doesn't fill zone between textview and slidingdrawer handle element.

If I swap embedded linearlayout and slidingdrawer I don't see handle element.

Please, help me with this trouble.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/event_tv_title"
        style="@style/EventTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

   <SlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/event_sd"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:content="@+id/content"
        android:handle="@+id/handle"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#00000000" >

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/handle"
           style="@style/TheatreRow"
           android:text="@string/schedule"/>

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/content"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="text" />
    </SlidingDrawer>


    <LinearLayout 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:background="@android:color/black">
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this Example: [This One.](https://mobibear.wordpress.com/2010/07/12/android-slidingdrawer-with-custom-view/)

Comment: Problem is if I set android:layout_height="fill_parent" for the event_tv_title my slidingdrawer is not visible

Comment: Thanks, I've found solution. I should use FrameLayout as root element instead of linearLayout.

Comment: @VasilYaroshevich:If you found solution then accept the answer so it can help others.